# Ajax.BeginForm on submit click not work and HTML.BeginForm returns partial view as view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-ajax, partial-views, unobtrusive-validation

i have a view in which there is a section and in section there are some links; section and one link are like this:

```
<section id="tabs-section">
<ul id="myTab" class="my-nav nav nav-tabs  nav-justified responsive-tabs col-sm-12" style="padding:0;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#RegisterEditUsers" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content col-sm-12" style="border:1px solid #000000;"@*margin-top:-20px;padding-top:20px;*@>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="RegisterEditUsers">@Html.Partial("RegisterEditUsers")</div>
        </div>
```

when i click on **A** a partial view in this view is shown under links. partial view is like this:

```
<div class="panel" style="border:1px solid #ff6a00;margin:10px 10px 0 
10px;padding:10px;">
<div class="row ">
        <div id="register" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-pull-0 
col-sm-push-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-pull-1 btn btn-circle ">
            @Ajax.ActionLink("AA", "Register", "Account", new AjaxOptions { 
HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "Result", InsertionMode = 
InsertionMode.Replace, OnComplete = "regClick" })
        </div>

        <div id="edit" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0 btn 
btn-circle">
            @Ajax.ActionLink("BB", "GetUsers", "UsersAdmin", new AjaxOptions 
{ HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "Result", InsertionMode = 
InsertionMode.Replace, OnComplete = "edClick" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="border:1px solid #ff6a00;margin:0px 10px 10px 
10px;">
<div id="Result" dir="rtl"></div>
</div>
```

and finally when i choose **AA** a new partial view is loaded bellow the former partial view, that is this:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Register", 
    "Account", 
    null, 
    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    UpdateTargetId = "IdentifyPerson",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
  }))
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" });

    <div id="IdentifyPerson" style="padding:10px">
        <div class="panel" style="padding:10px; direction:rtl">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="LastName">:</label>
                    @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName" 
placeholder="" name="LastName">*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.LastName, new { @class = "form-
control", placeholder = "" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", 
new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <button type="submit" id="RegisterBtn" 
name="RegisterBtn" class="btn btn-info" style="padding:10px">AAA</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

everything goes Good until i click on submit button (**AAA**), nothing is happened. i also use this line in my pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
```

if i use **HTML.BeginForm** instead of **Ajax.BeginForm** submit button works fine but in return part, when i want to load the second partial view, it is loaded as a view!!
**Question:** what i want is: when i click on submit button Ajax.BeginForm or HTML.beginForm works and returned page shows as partial view not a view.
any one can help me?

Comment: Have you also included `jquery-{version}.js`?

Comment: yes i do: <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")"></script>

Comment: thanks , i added into the partial view these four lines: <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-
3.1.1.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script> and it works fine, but partial view is already load as view !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to  Stephen Muecke, it seems that bundle not work properly. i don't know why really, i just added these four lines directly to partial view and it work fine :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-
3.1.1.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```